# Aggregation $addFields Mongo Morphia equivalent

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I want to use this below mongo query in morphia but cannot find `$addFields` morphia equivalent in `morphia 1.3.2`

```
db.getCollection('user').aggregate([
  { $addFields: {
    fullName: {
      $concat: ['$firstname',' ','$lastname']
    }
  }}
])
```

Then I match this query with : `aggregation.match(mongoQuery)`

Can someone help ?

Comment: can you share your mongo databse version?

Comment: > db.version()
4.0.12
>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregation support is pretty limited in 1.3.2.  The API was never fully implemented and was intended as a prototype and never quite finished.   However, I have been working to fix that in the upcoming 2.0 version.   I hope to do a new, probably, ALPHA release with a preview of the new complete API.  If you dont mind playing with snapshot builds you can it now.  Instructions for updating your pom are [here](https://github.com/MorphiaOrg/morphia/issues/1414#issuecomment-578517566).

Comment: Oh ok i didn't know that. I was trying my best to look for a documentation. 
Well i'll use projection for now and wait for the update :). Thx a lot.

Comment: 2.0.0-BETA2 is out now so you don't need to build anything.  just update your pom.